# Haskell skeleton template project for beginners

Tags: haskell, import, module

I have 3 data constructors say A,B and C that are defined in files A.hs, B.hs, C.hs and the files are in the directory project-utils.
Now I want to use these data constructors in parts of other projects. These projects reside in totally different directories.
How do I import the data and type constructors of A, B and C in such project files?

Thanks to the first answer given below, I realized that I am looking for a skeleton to organize such project in a better way. I searched but could not find any such project skeleton.
The link provided [there](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Structure_of_a_Haskell_project#Directory_Structure) contains many things that are described in vague manner. For example, on line 5 [there](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Structure_of_a_Haskell_project#Directory_Structure) it is simple written as "..."

What i am looking for is,
The skeleton project should not be very simple "single" file project as is given on the Haskell site. But should NOT be overly complex with tons of dependencies etc that we see in many projects on hackage.

Edit: I changed the title to reflect my problem in a better way. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 4):

1. Make a cabal pkg out of them and install that package locally.
2. Follow a directory stucture as [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Structure_of_a_Haskell_project) and use those constuctors in a project rather than across projects. The stucture mentioned is basically a structure of a cabal package.
3. Manually add the input source while compiling through `ghc` or loading in `ghci`. 
   Example

   ghci -i project-utils/A.hs Foo.hs

where `Foo.hs` uses elements exported by `A.hs`

Comment: Is there any beginner level skeleton template project available? I saw this post `http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2012/09/project-templates` but couldn't get any template. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

May not be exactly what you're looking for, but for future readers of this question, a Haskell skeleton/template project was just released here:

https://github.com/tfausak/haskeleton

It does add some dependencies like hlint and hspec.  Here is the blog post, which goes through each of the individual decisions:

http://taylor.fausak.me/2014/03/04/haskeleton-a-haskell-project-skeleton/

Answer (score 0):

I found this: [how to write a haskell program](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/How_to_write_a_Haskell_program) link as a handy reference.

@Tem Pora : you need to install yesod and yesod-bin. This link talks more about the [scaffolding](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/scaffolding-and-the-site-template)

```
cabal install yesod
cabal install yesod-bin
<cdtoprojdir> yesod init
```

Hope this helps.